# Getting null from while parsing data from Firebase Realtime Database Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image][image]I am integrating firebase realtime database,there are two list in firebase news & categories.

When I tried to get news from categoryId = 1 it works fine but as I choose categoryId = 2, I got two null values in my array response.

```
[
    null,
    null,
    {
        image="https://zdnet3.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/2016/06/29/a6f69a53-88f3-4e1b-9b59-2287c81e7671/bdc6cc9e6d26866aa44607d87e43f082/syme-ios-v-android.jpg",
        description="PrabhudasLilladheranalystAniketPandesaidinanote.Weremaincautiousonoveralldemandenvironmentandas",
        news_url="https://www.google.co.in",
        short_desc="AndroidisbetterthaniOS",
        title="Technology",
        categoryId="2"
    },
    {
        image="https://i.gadgets360cdn.com/large/oneplus_7T_pro_event_1570722059050.jpg?output-quality=80&output-format=webp",
        description="OnePlusLaunchEventstartedwiththecompany'sco-founderCarlPeionthestage.HebeganbytalkingaboutOxygenOS.PeicitedastudythatclaimsthatOxygenOSisoneofthetopthreereasonswhyOnePlususerslovethecompany.HealsotalkedaboutOxygenOSbetaprocessandhowithelpsthecompanygathersignificantamountoffeedbackabouttheoperatingsystembeforerollingoutanewversionwidely",
        news_url="https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/news/oneplus-7t-pro-launch-live-updates-mclaren-edition-london-price-specifications-2114715",
        short_desc="OnePlus7TProMcLarenEditionIsOfficial:LiveUpdates",
        title="Technology",
        categoryId="2"
    }
]
```

this is response I got from my query

```
 mChildReference = databaseReference.child("news_data").orderByChild("categoryId").equalTo(categoryId);

      mChildReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              Toast.makeText(context,dataSnapshot.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              String json =  dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
              try {
                  JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(json);

              } catch (Throwable t) {
                  Log.e("Catch", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + json + "\"");
              }
          }
          @Override
          public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

          }
      });
```

Error:
Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Please provide your DB Structure

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman please check I edited my question

Comment: Try my answer and let me know

Comment: By the way,  I can't see the categoryId 2 data

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman categoryId 2 is same as category 1 structure

Comment: Another point, you have received JSONArray from DB, but you trying to parse JSONObject. Is there any reason?

Comment: I am doing other thing of it, I got error on `String json` first priority is this

Answer (score 0):

Inside **`onDataChange`**, check like this:

```
    for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
        if(ds != null) {
            //Do stuff here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats why i check null, and bypass if null

Comment: can't understand what u want to say